# How to create System Field for auto generated URL in Wix?

Tags: velo

I am trying to create a System field in my Wix website for generating URL for my dynamic page, which is similar to one of their preset "team".

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the field "Team (Title)" is a System Field and it generates the URL for every new entry on its own and shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the database on the left-hand column. Click the gear icon that shows beside the database name and then select 'Add dynamic page'

At this point you will get the option to create your URL for the dynamic pages by choosing a prefix (**/Team**) and then you can select a Field from your database.

The image shows that the Team (Title) column in your database is set to create dynamic pages based on the field '**Name**' from your database along with the prefix of **/Team**

Read the support doc: https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-dynamic-pages-4488730

Comment: Thanks, this I understand. But I want to find out how to create autogenerated URL field. Like in this example when a new record with name "Fname Lname" a url is generated "/Team/Fname-Lname". 

now for my page I want the same to happen, but I want the prefix to the URL "/Team" to be something else.

Comment: In this case you will need to create a new dynamic page and while you are doing that you will be given the option to set the Prefix